# Restoring a database from .bak file on another machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-restore

I've not done much SQL and am still pretty new to this, so please excuse what's probably a basic question.

I've been asked to look into creating an SQL job to backup our databases, store the .baks on another machine and then to restore them to a second server. I've been doing a bit of research and playing with SSMS and have back-ed up the database to my personal machine by setting up a share and running a backup job to the share location. I'm now trying to create a new database (on the same server I back-ed up from) by restoring the .bak file (but giving the database I'm trying to create a new name and what-not) but am unable to specify restoring it from the share, like I did when backing it up/I can't find how to specify other network locations and am just browsing the server's C drive when I try to locate the file.

For now, I'm just using the built-in wizards to try and achieve this (open SSMS -> Connect to server -> right click DataBases -> Restore DataBases and then select From Device and browse to find the file).

This isn't the final process, just me trying to get to grips with how this works. As I said, the idea is to ultimately have a scheduled job to backup the DB from server1 to a .bak on, say, my personal machine and then to restore that to a DB on server2 (different network, different city) and, probably, with a series of SQL commands rather than using the wizard every time (there are a few DBs that'll, ultimately, need backing up).

My apologies for the, possibly, quite drawn out and convoluted question - essentially, all I need to know is can I/how can I restore a DB in SSMS from a .bak on a different machine?
Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import .bak file to a database in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535914/import-bak-file-to-a-database-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use something like the following script. It restores a database from the filesystem, and it overwrites the existing database with the name of "MyDB", moving the files to new locations of your choice in the process.

```
RESTORE DATABASE
    MyDB
FROM DISK = '\\MyShare\MyBackup.bak'
WITH 
    MOVE 'DataFile' TO 'D:\myNewDBLocation\DataFile.mdf',
    MOVE 'LogFile' TO 'E:\\myNewDBLocation\LogFile.ldf'
, REPLACE
```

You can find out the name of the llogical files (in the above, those are called `DataFile` and `LogFile` by running the following:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = '\\MyShare\MyBackup.bak'
```

Additional information about various options and parameters:

[RESTORE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. A couple of questions, 1) What are the DataFile and LogFiles? If restoring the DataBase to the same server/location (just whilst I'm getting to grips with it, I don't really want to be accessing the second server yet unless I really need to) would they still need to be moved?
2) I've attempted to restore with,
RESTORE DATABASE MyDB FROM DISK ='\\MyShare\MyDir\backup.bak WITH REPLACE'
but am getting the error:
"The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided."
Which I can't claim to understand, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The datafile(s) are files that contain actual data. The logifle is the transaction log is like a logfile of transactions that can be used to recover the data to a specific point in time in case of a crash.

Try running the RESTORE FILELISTONLY command to figure out which files are actually used by the database.

And yes, when restoring the database to the same server, you will need to move the files. Otherwise the new database will try to use the same files as the first database, which would not be possible.

Comment: Many thanks. Am now up and running :-)
Would upvote, but can't yet.