# Restore Sql Server database from client .bak file

Tags: sql-server

I have a .bak file on my client and want to use it, to restore a database on a server running on another machine. Is there any way to achieve this without transfering the file to the servers filesystem?

Comment: you can create the script of the DB (also with data) .. or even you can use a powershell script i think

Comment: The bak file was created by an admin on a prod database and i need it to restore the dev environment. I really need a solution to use the BAK file.

Comment: You can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396027/restoring-a-database-from-bak-file-on-another-machine

Comment: You can restore from any path, including from network folders. Have you tried *sharing* the folder where the backup file is stored?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.Share the folder containig .bak file on a server where you want to restore the database .Now paste the path when browsing the .bak file.