# How can I restore a SQL Server Data base to a file share location?

Tags: sql-server, restore

I am trying restore a SQL database from my SQL Server to a fileshare on another server.  I keep getting access denied (unable to open the physical file) message during the restore.

In short, I am trying to restore a backup to a network file share.

I have a server SQLSRV (SQL Server 2017; Windows 2012 R2) and FILESRV (Windows 2012 R2). Each night I run an automatic back of database A and restore to database B. Both databases have been on SQLSRV.  I just relocated the database B files to a fileshare on FILESRV.  With database B on FILESRV I have been able to attached, query, update, backup to SQLSRV and FILESRV without issue.  It appears the only thing I can't do is restore a backup from SQLSRV to FILESRV.  It indicates it's a permission problem, but I have set Full access to Everyone and both the Share and NTFS. I have run ProcMon on FILESRV while trying to backup. I see the file open request and it shows as successful.  I feel like I am overlooking something obvious, but I am at a loss.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the file needs to be on the local file system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restoring a database from .bak file on another machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396027/restoring-a-database-from-bak-file-on-another-machine)

Comment: @Renat the referenced duplicate question appears to be trying to restore files from a network share to the SQL server.  I am trying to restore files to a network share.  Thanks