# Importing .bak from MSSQL into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql-server

My companies site uses a mysql database. One of our clients just trying to take advantage of our API is only able to give us the data in the form of a MSSQL .bak file
I have been trying to import the file using the migration tool built inot mysql workbench but have no luck.
On top of that I am trying to see if this can be done in powershell as I would like to automate this process in the future.
Any suggestions or help would be appreciated

Comment: Such a ".bak" file is proprietary Microsoft format for SQL Server. [Restore it into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535914/import-bak-file-to-a-database-in-sql-server) and then copy over the *information*. (The schema will also need to be transferred/emulated appropriately.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. MS SQL Server backups are proprietary to MS SQL Server and cannot be used with any other RDBMS. You will need to restore this backup to SQL Server, then use an additional tool to transfer the data from SQL Server into MySQL.

Can you do that second portion through PowerShell? Probably. Though SSIS would probably be a better method.